# readr::read_file escape nul character

Tags: r, readr, nul

I have a badly structured text file which I want to transform into a tidy data frame. As a first step, I need to read the whole file, which I want to do using `readr::read_file("my_file.txt")`. Unfortunately, `read_file()` stops reading the file after a couple of rows *without* throwing an error or a warning.

I tried reading the file with `readr::read_lines()` and `readLines()`. `read_lines()` also stopped reading, this time only omitting the rear part of some rows. `readLines()` however returned a buch of warnings such as

```
Warning messages:
1: In readLines("data/fdb_export.txt") :
  line 1544 appears to contain an embedded nul
```

Using `readLines("my_file", skipNul = TRUE)` makes it possible to read all rows completely.

Is there a similar functionality in `readr`? The file is rather large and it would save some time if I would not have to read it in lines and then collapse it.